# Can the child documents inherit the Custom URL path of it's parent in Kentico

Tags: kentico

I have a situation where my client wants to have SEO friendly URLs for their documents and for these URLs to flow down to the client documents. Here is an example setup:

Root

- Groups

  - Group1 (custom url=/groups/ma/salem/group1)

    - Page1
    - Page2
  - Group2 (custom url=/groups/ma/boston/group2)

    - Page2
    - Page4
  - etc.

The would like Page1, Page2, Page3, Page4 to inherit it's parent's custom url and be:

- /groups/ma/salem/group1/page1
- /groups/ma/salem/group1/page2
- /groups/ma/boston/group2/page2
- /groups/ma/boston/group2/page3

When I set the Custom URL path it only affects that document and the child documents stay the same:

- /groups/group1/page1
- /groups/group1/page2
- /groups/group2/page2
- /groups/group2/page3

Can this be achieved in Kentico without modifying the tree structure to contain the URL parts?

Is there a way to override the ResolveURL() function so i can return the SEO friendly URL?

I'm using Kentico 8.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating those document in the tree would be definitely the easiest and safest solution, but taken you want to avoid this I see two other options.

1) Create URL rewriting rules to simulate this tree hierarchy

2) Catch document insert before event and set the custom URL path according your needs.

Code could look something like this:

```
DocumentEvents.Insert.Before += DocumentInsert_Before;

private static void DocumentInsert_Before(object sender, DocumentEventArgs e)
{
    TreeNode node = e.Node;

    if (node.NodeAliasPath.StartsWith("/groups/group1")) {
        string safeNodeName = TreePathUtils.GetSafeDocumentName(node.DocumentName, CMSContext.CurrentSiteName);
        string customPath = "/groups/ma/salem/group1/" + safeNodeName;

        // Handle multiple dashes
        customPath = TreePathUtils.GetSafeUrlPath(path, CMSContext.CurrentSiteName, true);

        node.DocumentUrlPath = customPath;
    }
}
```